# Dynamic DNS port forwarding

Tags: tcp, routes, webserver, dns

I need to use my computer as a server but my ISP blocks port 80, 21, 23 etc. I can use other ports and some dynamic dns service but I don't want:

- (HTTP) Users have to type http://mydynamicdnsaddress:#port#
- (HTTP) Users be redirected from http://mydynamicdnsaddress to http://mydynamicdnsaddress:#port#
- (HTTP) Some kind of service that gets HTTP response and change it before resending to users. No-ip and GoDaddy do that. They change some parts of html - eg: title.
- Users have to type ftp://mydinamicdnsaddress:#port#

I believe that I need some kind of dynamic dns service that points to a router that forwards TCP packets to another address changing ports. Do you know any online service like that?

Answer (score 7):

Many "dynamic DNS companies use HTTP redirection to send the browser from port 80 to a different port. When you ask a dynamic DNS company to point your domain to a port other than 80, what they actually do is point the domain to their own web-server IP address (in DNS), and then on their web-server (running on port 80) they have a simple server side script which redirects the browser to the your web-server on whatever port you specified - optionally "cloaked" so the visitor won't notice." [Can I specify a TCP/IP port number for my web-server in DNS? (Other than the standard port 80)](http://www.simpledns.com/kb.aspx?kbid=1042)

Here's a reference article for a redirection script: [Redirect Script](http://www.simpledns.com/kb.aspx?kbid=1151).

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is a tunnel or proxy.  You'd set up a server which receives communications via port (e.g.) 80 and proxies that request to your home server on port-whatever.  You'd probably need to get a dedicated host (or VM like linode) in order to do this.  At that point, you might as well move your webserver to the unblocked host.

Also, to be clear, this is impossible with pure DNS.  DNS, "Domain Name System", resolves names to IP addresses, NOT to IP address/port pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Most dynamic DNS service providers also provide free web redirect or port forwarding such as dynu.com.

Please note that the cloak works by loading the page in a frame of sort and it does not work with all browsers. For example, Chrome does not support cloak.

As far as I know, you cannot specify the port number in the DNS unless the web server which  performs redirection is clever enough to read out the TXT record and use it for redirection. Any web server doing that would be really nice though.